# get function returns a string with len = 0 in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, get

I created GUI(tkinter) inside a Button named "Edit" And also entry widget in it and when I tried to extract text of entry widget using textvariable. get() I couldn't do so it just returns an empty string ,len=0 of course.... Although I typed some thing in entry box
"EDIT" function is actually command of another button which I didn't include here...

```
def edit():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('EDIT-CONTACTS')
    can2 = Canvas(root,width = 800,height = 1000,bg = '#FFE4C4')
    can2.pack()


    def gop():
        sget = var3.get()
        print(sget)


    can2.create_text(380,30,text= 'ENTER A NAME TO EDIT',font = 'comicsansms 10 bold')
    can2.create_text(100,200,text= 'NAME : ',font = 'comicsansms 9 italic')

    var3 = StringVar()
    entryo = Entry(root, textvariable = var3 ,bd = 7,font = 'comicsansms 8 bold')

    entryy = can2.create_window(480,200,window= entryo)

    b = Button(root,text= 'Press',command=gop)
    b.place(x=500,y=500)
```

Comment: Is the `root` in this code a second instance of `Tk`?  You should never create more than one.

Comment: Ohh!! Thanks Bryan I'll now use TopLevel function